# directed trees versus singly-connected directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, trees

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree), a singly connected directed graph (a.k.a. Polytree) is a Directed Acyclic Graph whose underling undirected graph is a tree. How is this different from directed trees (trees where we orient their edges arbitrary) ?

Comment: There is no difference; what you’re calling a directed tree is also called an oriented tree, and the Wikipedia article notes that *oriented tree* is another name for a polytree.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks. I expected to see you answering this :) . Is there a difference between directed-trees and oriented trees (Polytrees) then ? ( I have a paper where authors distinguish between the two without defining them)

Comment: There can be: I’ve seen *directed tree* used to mean a rooted tree oriented so that all edges point away from the root.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "According to wikipedia, a singly connected directed graph (a.k.a. Polytree) is a Directed Acyclic Graph whose underling undirected graph is a tree" Is the "acyclic" property necessary?